# How do I get mysql results for multiple date ranges?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure someone will have a very simple answer to this but I can't work it out for the life of me: I have 3 tables that look something like this:

`Vehicles: Vehicle_id, Reg_number...`
`Datalogger: Logger_id, event, status, date...`
`Vehicle_Loggers: Vehicle_id, Logger_id, installed_from, installed_to`

(Relationships are on columns with the same name here)

Using these tables how would I get the whole history of a given vehicle's logs (event and status) even if it has had multiple loggers fitted at different times?

I know this can be done using a cursor but as this is really a set operation (Get the set of loggers that have been attached to the vehicle, then get the reports of each logger using the given date range for that logger)

**EDIT:** Loggers can be used in more than one vehicle during their lifetime, hence the inclusion of the dates.

Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select v.Reg_number, d.* from Vehicles v
inner join Vehicle_Loggers vl on vl.Vehicle_id = v.Vehicle_id
inner join Datalogger d on d.Logger_id = vl.Logger_Id
where v.Reg_number = ...
```

Just replace the Reg_number for the intended one.

---

To take in account the dates, possibly would be like this:

```
select v.Reg_number, d.* from Vehicles v
inner join Vehicle_Loggers vl on vl.Vehicle_id = v.Vehicle_id
inner join Datalogger d on d.Logger_id = vl.Logger_Id and d.date between vl.installed_from and vl.installed_to
where v.Reg_number = ...
```

Comment: Afaik this doesn't take into account the installed dates so we'd get the history for each logger no matter which vehicle it was attached to.

Comment: @ridecar2 try the second query then :)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly (never realised you could use multiple conditions in a JOIN clause.)